# Entity Framework - how to use object array of classes

Tags: entity-framework, object

I`m having a class:

```
public class Player
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // May be Class A, Class B, ..., Class Z
    public object[] Inventory {get; set;}
}
```

How can to create sql table from this code? 
EF creates just:

```
create table [dbo].[Players] (
    [Id] [int] not null identity,
    [Name] [nvarchar](max) null,
    primary key ([Id])
);
```

without object[]

Comment: or may be some advice? I need object array to store different classes entire.

Comment: As I understand it is not possible. I need to create Class A with link to parent class Player. However there are several parent classes, not only Player